# Dynamic Datatables with grunt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, angular-datatables

I have a Sample project with angular-datatables with CRUD operations. I looked at Project Scaffolding at grunt web, but I can't find anything about javascript templates that fit my needs...

I saw init.copyAndProcess that is something like I want, but I need few improves to this. First, I want templates with conditional sentences on my js file, like(pseudocode):

```
{if prop.selectAllButton} 
//declare header render on Datatables in several lines of code{/if}
```

Also,  there will be like 10 or 20 options, and it could grow with the number of columns or by creating virtual columns. So, I want the props object to be on a file, not to be prompts on cli.

The table is not rendered in angular way.

Thanks in advance.
Chi.

Comment: Could you clarify what you need help with?

Comment: I want to generate a js dynamically based on a json config file, and I dont know what to use.
Thx for the response.

Comment: So, basically you are looking for someone who want to write a angular datatables generator for you..?

Comment: No... I was lookig for someone to teel me to use yeoman and gulp...

http://yeoman.io/generator/Base.html
Used to read the config file, that was the question...

I was bothered by your comment...

Comment: @ChiramMFM, sry - it was not my intention to be offensive, more like interrogative (english is not my first language)

Comment: @davidkonrad no problem, it's normal that at first read you thought that I was lazy and only want to find my code... but my intention is to learn about grunt, gulp, yeo and all js task runners. English is not my first language neither, and the question was very basic, so that was my fault too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now i see that my questions is a bit obvious to answer if I move out of grunt Scaffolding and use yeoman...

In yo file, I can read my configFile in the initializing phase, like:

```
 initializing: function () {
    this.pkg = require('../package.json');
    this.dtconfig = require(this.options['config-file-location']);
},
```

Where 'config-file-location' is an argument of the cli.

Them, in the writing phase, I use dtconfig as parameter for copyTpl:

```
  scripts: function () {
  this.fs.copyTpl(
    this.templatePath('main.js'),
    this.destinationPath('app/scripts/main.js'),
    {//Parameters
      selectAllButton: this.dtconfig.selectAllButton
     }
  );
```

And them, in the templates/main.js file:

```
<% if (selectAllButton) { %>
//apply selectaAll header render for dt.
```